Reading XLSX file using Google Sheet API?
We are using the Google API to read sheet data from Google Sheets (in Node.js):
  const res = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(
    {
      spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
      range: sheetName,
      auth: credentials
    }
  );
  return res.data.values;

The issue we are running into is that some users are uploading .XLSX files and then just working with them as regular Google Sheets. This breaks the code we are using with the following error:

This operation is not supported for this document

While we could try to educate the users on why these need to resaved as Google Sheets (instead of an Excel file), I'd like to see if there is a way we can just handle these files using a Google API?
Does anyone know if this is possible?
Note: We are not looking to convert the document, but read it using the Google Sheets API or similar API. The service account we are using is not authorised to use the Google Drive API. Also, conversion would mean we would be needing to do create a temporary file every time we need to read the document contents.

This question is similar to: How to Convert XLSX to Sheets in Google Drive API v3. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is not about converting, but reading unconverted.

I think you probably cant directly read xlsx, but if you have control over the upload of the file you should be able to basically programmatically convert the xlsx to google spreadsheet and then read it, should be simple enough as you leverage the builtin convert operation of google sheets

I am trying to avoid the human issue, of telling users they need to convert their files, by seeking a technical solution. If I need to create a drive for temporary files and then convert the file every time I need to read it, then I'll go there, though I'd rather avoid that if Google offers a better solution. Training the users may be a requirement too.

I understand that you are trying to read it without any conversion however, in the current stages of the Google Sheets it is not allowed. However, the workaround I do have in mind that can help you is to convert it, which in this case is on the link that I have shared with you. convert-xlsx-to-sheets
